# How to add library in custom GIMP filter?

Tags: gimp

I need to create GIMP filter with ability to send and receive XMPP messages. I downloaded and installed GIMP plugin template from http://developer.gimp.org/plug-in-template.html , and it works. I also have Loudmouth XMPP plugin (sorry, I can't post more links) , and I would like to include that plugin in GIMP plugin template.

I was told that I have to add

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LOUDMOUTH, loudmouth-1.0)  
AC_SUBST(LOUDMOUTH_CFLAGS)  
AC_SUBST(LOUDMOUTH_LIBS)
```

in configure.in. There I already have

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GIMP,  
  gimp-2.0 >= $GIMP_REQUIRED_VERSION gimpui-2.0 >= $GIMP_REQUIRED_VERSION)  

AC_SUBST(GIMP_CFLAGS)  
AC_SUBST(GIMP_LIBS)
```

Also, I was told that I have to add LOUDMOUTH_CFLAGS and LOUDMOUTH_LIBS to src/Makefile.am.
In Makefile.am I already have:

```
INCLUDES =\  
 -I$(top_srcdir)  \  
 @GIMP_CFLAGS@  \  
 -I$(includedir)  
  
LDADD = $(GIMP_LIBS)
```

How to write this? How to add this librabry in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@LOUDMOUTH_CFLAGS@ \` below the line `@GIMP_CFLAGS@`. As for the libs, try:

```
LDADD = $(GIMP_LIBS) @LOUDMOUTH_LIBS@
```

or

```
LOUDMOUTH_LIBS = @LOUDMOUTH_LIBS@
LDADD = $(GIMP_LIBS) $(LOUDMOUTH_LIBS)
```